# How should i mention short time empolyment on my CV when moving to a sector where this is uncommon?

Tags: resume

Several months ago i took a job working on a short term project. That project is coming to an end, which means i have to find something new. However, the jobs i'm looking for now are in a different sector where project-based work is not common.

**Will companies be scared off by seeing this short time employment on my CV?** If so, how can i make it clear that short term work is common in the other sector, and that i would have preferred something more long term?

This is my only work experience, so leaving it off my CV is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think companies will be scared off by this, even if their sector doesn't tend to work in fixed projects.  I would just ensure you mention that this was a fixed term role, and emphasise the skills you learned/experience you gained as part of it.

For a first job it can actually be tougher to take on a role like this, there is likely to be less hand holding getting into the role, so make sure you make a point of this in your CV, be positive about it.